# 'include' files not running queries

Tags: php, browser, include

I've never seen this before, and am not even really sure I can explain it properly, but I desperately need a solution.

My website uses header and footer files. When you access the files directly from the browser, they work fine. But when I access them through another file using the "include" function, the queries on the files do not work.
In my case, the header and footer files need to establish whether or not the viewer is logged in. And the files work just fine on their own. If I access the files directly through the browser (by address: website/html/header.php), the queries function and the results are correct.
If I go to my index.php page, which uses: include("$webpath/html/header.php"); the queries in the header.php file do not return the correct data.

I've just recently transferred the website to a new webhost. The files were working just fine on the previous webhost, so I'm assuming it's a setting or something in the webhost? Althought I don't see anything relating to that in my control panel, and the webhost swears that it should function properly.

Any ideas? I would greatly appreciate any input.

Comment: Is $webpath variable correct?

Comment: yeah checked the $webpath variable!

Comment: When you switch on `error_reporting(E_ALL)` what does it say, any errors?

Answer (score 1):

You could always do:

```
<?php 
function loadContent($file){
    if(!file_exists($file)){die($file.' not found.');}
    ob_start();
    require($file);
    $return = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $return;
}

echo loadContent("$webpath/html/header.php");
?>
```